# The proof of the riesz representation theorem (the one that obtains a radon measure from a positive linear funtional).

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The question is from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 2.14, which states that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\Lambda:C_c(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ is a positive linear functional, then there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{m}$ and a radon measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathscr{m}$ s.t. $\Lambda f=\int{f}d\mu$ for all $f\in C_c(X)$ and all elements in $\mathscr{m}$ of finite measures are inner regular.

I read through the proof. The only thing that baffles me is how the author constructs the $\sigma$-algebra. Here is how he did it,

First of all, we set up some notations for convenience. Let $K$ be a compact set, $V$ be an open set. The notation $K\prec f$ means $f$ is a continuous function s.t. $0\leq f\leq1$ and $f\equiv1$ on $K$ and the notation $f\prec V$ means $f$ is a continuous function s.t. $0\leq f\leq1$ and $\mathrm{supp}\,f\subset V$.

If $V$ is an open set, let $\mu(V)=\sup{\{\Lambda f:f\prec V\}}$. For any $A\subset X$, define $\mu(A)=\inf{\{\mu(V):A\subset V\}}$. He then defines $\mathscr{m}_F$ to be the collection of all subsets $A\subset X$ s.t. $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $A$ is inner-regular, i.e., can be approximated from inside by compact sets. Finally, he lets $\mathscr{m}$ to be all subsets $A\subset X$ s.t. $A\cap K\in\mathscr{m}$ for all compact subset $K\subset X$.

I can't find an obvious reason why the author decided to define the $\sigma$-algebra in this way. Can anyone help me with this if you have some ideas? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The author wants to find a measure which is outer regular, and inner regular on finite-measure sets. So to start building the $\sigma$-algebra he chooses precisely the sets where the outer measure he defined has those properties. Another requirement is to be finite on compact sets, and this is what $\mathfrak m_F$ is. Why he starts with the finite-measure sets and then moves to the actual $\sigma$-algebra, I would say it's because the proof works that way.

Comment: I can see why he decided to define $\mathbf{m}_F$. But I am still confused why he defines $\mathbf{m}$ using $\mathbf{m}_F$. My guess is he tries to include all the borel sets since not all borel sets have finite measures. But I can't relate it to how he actually defines $\mathbf{m}$

Comment: Not really sure what you are expecting. You need $\mathfrak m$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra, so it cannot consist of just finite sets, because countable unions of them will likely have infinite measure.